# About subscriber and publisher node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is subscriber and publisher node coding will be in the same cpp file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51801/about-subscriber-and-publisher-node/) by [kala](https://answers.ros.org/users/3929/kala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-09**:
What do you want to do? Reformulate that question, so it is understandable. For now my guess answer is: No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to create two different nodes, one publishing a topic and the other subscribing to its messages, they will need different .cpp files for their sources.

If you want a single node that subscribes to one topic and publishes to another, than can be done in a single .cpp file.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0